# manually registering devices for GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

So everywhere I look, registering a device involves using google's Tomcat server, setting that up, and then registering the device against it. Is this the only way to register the device? Are there bindings in other languages or ways to reproduce the register functionality without using their Tomcat server? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build GCM registration server in any language, I have mine in `PHP` so it does not need to be Java at all.

The GCM APIs uses `JSON` messages to communicate with the Google service so almost any language is capable of send `JSON` HTTP request.

Here an example `PHP` server to handle `GCM` registration

```
    $apiKey = "YOUR KEY";
    $registrationIDs = "REGISTRATION IDs";

    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(        
            'collapse_key' => $collapse_key,
            'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
            'data'              => $data_array,
            'time_to_live' => $time_to_live
            );

    $headers = array( 
                'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );

    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

[Here is a Python GCM server](https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm)

Comment: i looked over http://developer.android.com/google/gcm, the source of the server stuff wasn't immediately visible. do you know of python bindings or a place to view the java source to get an understanding of what is being requested and where ?

Comment: the code you wrote ended up being helpful, using it as a template for my own, thanks.